# Why is my apache basic authentication configuration not prompting for login?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx-server, apache-2.4

I am running `Apache 2.4.9` with `PHP 5.5.9` through `OS X Server Beta 3.5 (14S171z)`.

I have the following configuration in my `.htaccess` that resides in a directory that I would like to be protected using basic authentication:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /absolute/path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
IndexIgnore *
```

VirtualHost conf (managed by `OS X Server`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName REDACTED
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/absolute/path/to/document/root"
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php /wiki/ /xcode/ default.html
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combinedvhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine Off
        SSLCipherSuite "ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM"
        SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
    </IfModule>
    <Directory "/absolute/path/to/document/root">
        Options All -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            DAV Off
        </IfModule>
        <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
            Deny from all
            ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
    ServerAlias REDACTED
</VirtualHost>
```

The following modules are enabled (This is a partial list):

```
authn_file_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
access_compat_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
```

When I attempt to access any file in the directory that has the `.htaccess`, I get `403 Forbidden` and the following is logged in the error log:

```
[Thu Jun 05 14:09:55.598801 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 59601] [client REDACTED] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /absolute/path/to/a/file/in/the/folder/with/htaccess
```

Shouldn't I be prompted for authentication instead of 403 Errors?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite suspicious:

```
        <IfDefine !WEBSERVICE_ON>
            Deny from all
            ErrorDocument 403 /customerror/websitesoff403.html
        </IfDefine>
```

If that isn't defined somewhere, then all requests will be denied long before it ever gets to your .htaccess file.